# Trouble using react-native-nested-stylesheet in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I was trying to create Nested Stylesheets with the use of "react-native-nested-stylesheet" (https://github.com/pjjanak/react-native-nested-stylesheets/) but it give this error once I install this.

```
Error building DepdendencyGraph:
 Error: Naming collision detected: /Users/hms-mac/research/react-native/myapp-mock/myapp/node_modules/react-native-nested-stylesheet/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/polyfills/polyfills.js collides with /Users/hms-mac/research/react-native/myapp-mock/myapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/polyfills/polyfills.js
    at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (/Users/hms-mac/research/react-native/myapp-mock/myapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:123:13)
    at /Users/hms-mac/research/react-native/myapp-mock/myapp/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:95:28
    at tryCallOne (/Users/hms-mac/research/react-native/myapp-mock/myapp/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/hms-mac/research/react-native/myapp-mock/myapp/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:103:15
    at flush (/Users/hms-mac/research/react-native/myapp-mock/myapp/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:428:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:357:13)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! myapp@0.0.1 start: `react-native start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.0.1 start script 'react-native start'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the myapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-native start
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls myapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/hms-mac/research/react-native/myapp-mock/myapp/npm-debug.log
```

What is causing this? If this persists, is there an alternative to create Nested Stylesheets? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but this package seems to be broken. See open issue number 1 from 2015, on the issues tab of the project on github.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't claim to entirely understand the solution. I think it had something to do with either incorrect addresses recorded to navigate node_modules, or it may have been my version of watchman was outdated or corrupted.

I fixed the issue by reinstalling watchman and deleting/recreating the node_modules and package-lock.json files.

```
npm cache clean --force

rm -rf node_modules

rm -rf package-lock.json

brew uninstall watchman

npm r -g watchman

npm install watchman

yarn

npm install

react-native link

npm start
```

Some of the steps might be expendable but it took me a long time so I wanted it to be watertight.

Good luck.